# Синтаксис css кода

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, табличная-верстка

Прочел https://habr.com/ru/company/pechkin/blog/256853/ и столкнулся с таким кодом

```
        table[class=contenttable] { 
        width:320px !important;
 }.
```

1. Что за синтаксис `тег[class=contenttable]` (почему нельзя использовать `.contenttable`)?
2. Что означает `!important`?

Answer (score 2):

синтаксис такой:

```
тег[имя_атрибута=значение]
```

То есть не обязательно там класс. Например, элемент:

```
<div my_tag="test"></div>
```

css: `div[my_tag=test]`

Свойство `!important` - если у вас для элемента действует более 1 значения какого-то css свойства, приоритетным по умолчанию будет последнее. Если же указать в одном из них `!important`, приоритетным будет оно, независимо от порядка.

Comment: _Если же указать в одном из них !important, приоритетным будет оно, независимо от порядка._ - если только ниже не объявлено такое же с !important :-)